# Conversion from text file to tuple functioning intermittently

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the following function:

```
def read_data(filename):

    lines = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]

    coordinates = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]

    coordinates = [(float(c[0]), float(c[1])) for c in coordinates]

    return tuple(coordinates)
```

That reads and converts to a tuple [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zchnpq0tbi4yhue/problem0.dat), just fine.

However, it fails on [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9n6dr81v3b47bhp/problem1.dat) and on [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/380nx4jci7840av/problem2.dat).

with

```
coordinates = [(float(c[0]), float(c[1])) for c in coordinates]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Why does this error appear and why doesn't it appear when reading problem0.dat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing on this line:

```
82.0  7.0
```

And any other line with two adjacent whitespace characters, because you're using `line.split(' ')` to split up each line. When you use `' '` as the separator, `split` call returns `['82.0', '', '7.0']`, which isn't what you want, and breaks your program. You can fix the issue by using `line.split()` instead, which will handle multiple adjacent whitespace characters properly.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) explain this behavior:

> **str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])**
>
> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and
> are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',')
> returns ['1', '', '2']). The sep argument may consist of multiple
> characters (for example, '1<>2<>3'.split('<>') returns ['1', '2',
> '3']). Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns
> [''].
>
> ...
>
> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting
> algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a
> single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the
> start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

The first file works because it doesn't have any entries with two consecutive whitespace characters.